# How to return value from api call in simple dialog model in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, endpoint

I have angular 8 application.

And I just want to show the text from api call in dialog mode.

So this is the api call in the component: FirstViewModalComponent

Comment: About your error use the safe navigation navigator (?) as result is undefined on the component initialisation : `{{result?.WelcomePopupBody}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add result of call to component property `this.healthApiService.getWelcomePopupsByParticipant().subscribe(result => this.result);`

Use it in view, html show with innerHtml binding and other properties with interpolation. Also you need to wrap template content so it won't render while results are undefined (Since you are making async call to backend I supose).

```
<app-modal [modalTitle]="modalTitle" [modalId]="modalId" (closeModal)="close.emit(false)">
  <ng-container *ngIf="results; else loading">
    <div class="modal modal-first-view">
      <div class="modal-text modal-text-first-view" [innerHtml]="result.welcomePopupBody">


      </div>
      <div class="first-view-button-wrap">
        <button (click)="buttonClicked()" type="button" class="button button-double-shadow button-first-view">
          {{ result.welcomePopupButtonText }}
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-img modal-img-first-view first-view-lady">
        <img src="/assets/img/Woman-coach.png" alt="Nice lady here to help" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-template #loading>
    ...Loading
  </ng-template>
</app-modal>
```

You need to use *ngIf to ensure you access properties of result object after it was inicialized. Usage of ng-container and ng-template is just example.

Comment: `        <div class="modal-text modal-text-first-view" [innerHtml]="result.WelcomePopupBody">
         {{result?.WelcomePopupBody}}    
        </div>`

Don't use both [innerHtml] binding and interpolation {{}}. Use only one. Either you want to bind proper HTML or text. Also consider upvoting or marking answer.

Comment: oke, if I do this:   <div class="modal-text modal-text-first-view"  [innerHtml]="result.WelcomePopupBody"> I get lot of erros, and If I do this: <div class="modal-text modal-text-first-view">      
      {{result.WelcomePopupBody}}
    </div> I dont get any errors, but nothing is showing. The text from api is: "welcomePopupBody": "<p>jklhlkjlkj</p>",

Comment: first-view-modal.component.html:3 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'WelcomePopupBody' of undefined
    at Object.updateRenderer (first-view-modal.component.html:3)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:30563)

Comment: ngOnInit() {
    this.updateScreenDimensions();
    const test = this.healthApiService.getWelcomePopupsByParticipant()
    .subscribe(result => {
      console.log(result);
      this.result});
  }

Comment: you need to define result property above constructor add result: any; and in ngoninit this.result = result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220021/discussion-between-nicetobebottleinfinity-and-matus-jurika).